# Enola Gay's Bad Day

Tags: warfare, alternate-history, nuclear-weapons

So it's 1945 and the US has sent a bomber to drop the first nuclear weapon on Hiroshima. The crew arm the weapon and are just about to drop it but something goes horribly wrong and they are unable to correct it or disarm the bomb before the plane nose dives into the ground.

Since Little Boy used a barometer to decide when to detonate, would the bomb go off while the plane was still falling, or would the impact be enough to trigger it?

Comment: I suggest you move "Also, what would be the political ramifications of this?" to a separate question after this question gets answered. Putting two questions in the same question muddies the thread and leads to mixed up conversations.

Comment: I took your advice.

Comment: This does not appear to be a question about worldbuilding; rather, it is a question about the mechanisms of a device that existed in 1945 of the real timeline for the real Earth.

Comment: The original question asked if this was possible in addition to the political ramifications that would be caused by this change in the timeline.

Comment: Why would Enola Gay crash if the bomb was still on board? It's somewhat undesireable to land a fully loaded plane, but the B-29 was designed to carry nine tons of bombs, Little Boy was only four tons. Hardly makes a difference in a plane of 30 tons empty and up to 60 at takeoff.

Comment: @Frostfyre a question about the mechanisms of a device ... *for the purposes of creating a fictional world*, as the edit history shows. It could be clearer, but this is as ambiguous as half the questions on the site, so it is within topic realm. Voting to leave open.

Comment: @Karl I think the point is "something goes horribly wrong"... that's the author's plot, and it's not relevant to the question for us to know why the plane is crashing.

Comment: @Frostfyre I'm also voting to leave this one open. It's inside my personal grey area (and I'm trying to recalibrate to give more leeway for the prevailing community standards of WB). I am a strong advocate for moving reality questions to site-specific exchanges, but since it is a hypothetical about a specific event and not a general physics question, I've decided to vote to Leave Open. YMMV.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [fusing system on Little Boy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Boy#Fuze_system) is much more robust than you may have first thought.  The result would be no nuclear explosion.

The barometer was only one of 3 parts of the fusing mechanism.  It didn't actually set off the bomb.  In fact, its real purpose was to prevent the bomb from going off too early.

In addition to arming steps, the three layers of fusing were:

- A timer circuit triggered by the disconnect of power cables from the plane as the bomb fell.  If the bomb got jammed, this one would never trigger.
- The barometric fuse you mentioned was designed to make sure the bomb could not explode too early.  When the pressure was high enough, it *enabled* the radar fuses.  This would be enabled as the plane descended, but would not matter.
- The radar altimeters were the final fuse, which were actually able to set off the bomb.  These would be looking straight forward in the bomb bay, and would certainly be reading the wrong altitude (because they would be measuring the distance to the bulkhead in front of them).  I don't have any sources covering what would happen in such a case, but I would expect that they would have kept a safeguard in place which prevented detonation if the altimeter data didn't look right.

Most of these fuse mechanisms would not trigger, so the bomb would not detonate.  Instead, the plane would simply crash.  The political ramification would depend heavily on what the Japanese manage to recover from the wreckage.

Also worth noting is that the 3 arming plugs which prevented the entire fusing mechanism from receiving sufficient power had to be manually inserted into the bomb in flight.  If the incident you describe were to occur, Morris Jeppson would simply have to remove one of these plugs to render the bomb non-functional.

Comment: So the impact could not set it off?

Comment: Decidedly not.  It's actually surprisingly difficult to make an atomic bomb explode.  Its very particular about geometry, and geometry is typically not preserved during crashes.  Perhaps if the aircraft nose dived in act *exactly* 90 degree as at 300m/s (the intended velocity of the "bullet" at detonation of the bomb), and the crash somehow didn't bend the tube the bullet traveled in in the slightest, you could get lucky.  It's also plausible the initiator could go off in the crash, but its unlikely something ferocious enough to set off an initiator unintentionally wouldn't damage the tube.

Comment: As a general rule, people who work with atomic bombs are the kind who do not like surprises.  They're pretty rigorous in making sure the bombs only do exactly what they are expected to do.  One example of where this was important was in takeoff of the Enola Gay.  The bomb was actually so heavy that there would be no opportunity to do a "go around" if anything went wrong with the takeoff.  The solution was that, in a "go around," the Gay was expected to drop the bomb first, to reduce mass, then go around to land.  This meant dropping the bomb on Tinitian. It needed to not explode.

Comment: I'm not sure the plugs could be removed in flight once installed. I'm not familiar with the exact design of the WW2 bombs, but some later ones had metal chains or ball bearings inserted in a cavity in the weapon to prevent criticality that once removed could not be inserted again without special equipment that was only available on bases.

Comment: @jwenting Good point.  All sources I read said the dummy plugs had to be removed, but nothing I read talked about whether the real plugs could be removed.  I didn't see any visible differences between the two plugs in the photos, but that doesn't mean a difference did not exist.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure they would want to disarm the bomb if they were going down over Japan. I'm sure this was discussed back at the time, but it seems to me that letting the Japanese get a hold of the bomb intact is much worse than detonating it somewhere random (as long as the explosion doesn't endanger US forces, etc).

Comment: @CortAmmon were the dummies removed in flight or before departure? I know the arming procedure involved a crew member crawling through the bomb bay, balancing on girders and the bomb itself. Not an environment for really delicate work.

Comment: @jwenting "Jeppson's role was to climb into the bomb bay and remove the three green safety plugs from the bomb and to replace them with the three red plugs just before the aircraft climbed to high altitude close the target area, a job that later caused controversy."([Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morris_R._Jeppson))

Comment: @CortAmmon not a job I'd like to have. I'm no trapeze artist :)

Comment: The bomb probably *will* go off.  Not in the crash, but in the post-crash fire.  Unlike implosion-type weapons, gun-type weapons don't rely on precisely-timed explosions to create a critical mass.  A fiery crash is sufficient to bring the two halves of the core together, and this risk was recognized at the time: the contingency plans for *Enola Gay* aborting the mission involved ditching the bomb at sea if the airplane was in anything less than perfect condition.

Answer (score 4):

## No change

First, I am going to assume that the bomb detonates as you describe, with the barometer and whatever other means necessary to make it happen occurring.

Little Boy is gravity dropped, so it doesn't get armed until right over the target. Once released, the bomb continues on a ballistic trajectory to its target. If the plane is shot down, then I imagine the remains of the plane continue on a ballistic trajectory to its target. Gravity works the same way for both.

Counting against this is the fact that the plane will have more air resistance from all its flight services, and wouldn't have followed exactly the same path as the bomb. Counting for this, is that [Paul Tibbets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Tibbets), the aircraft commander, had been specially selected to command the Atomic Bombing unit (509th Composite Wing), and fly the first drop, and was aware that he was dropping the biggest bomb of all. I would assume that he knew that jumping out on a parachute would leave him just as dead (and that knowing what he knew, he shouldn't get captured anyways) and would probably do his best to deliver the bomb/wreckage on target.

In conclusion, if the bomb had been armed, then the plane shot down, the result would be little different. The bomb goes off, maybe a few miles away, but Hiroshima is still nuked.

Comment: correct. At most the propaganda value of the event, which depended in part on interviews and photos of the aircraft and crew, would have been impeded. But in wartime it's quick and easy to change the story and show another aircraft instead, swearing those involved to secrecy about what really happened (especially as they were all confined to a small island reached only by military transport).

Comment: If the crew had got dead while delivering the bomb, the only difference from a propaganda point of view would have been that the US would have got a handful of heroes. That would have been helpful to focus in the American military heroes instead of the Japanese civil victims.

Comment: Little Boy and Fat Man were parachute dropped, as I recall -- this to ensure the drop plane had time to get well clear of the detonation.  Gravity fall (even from nearly ten km altitude) wouldn't take long enough.  Also, a shoot-down would likely have been by a flak battery (the Japanese were running quite low on fighter pilots by that time and a B-29 wasn't a soft target), so even if the bomb detonated (unlikely due to the multiple fuse cutouts) it would be miles from its intended target.  "We bombed a random location in Japan" isn't nearly as good as "We bombed an industrial target."